# JDBC hibernate Resultset won't access any column

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jdbc

I'm working with a Postgres db in java with java.sql. Can't copy the whole snippet due to nda, but it looks like this:

```
private final PostgresConnection postgresConnection = PostgresConnection.getInstance();
preparedStatement = postgresConnection.getConnection().
    prepareStatement("Insert into someTable(someColumn) values(?) RETURNING id");
preparedStatement.setString(i, (String) someParam);

resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
resultSet.next();

ResultSetMetaData meta = resultSet.getMetaData();

LOGGER.info("column count {}", meta.getColumnCount());

LOGGER.info("column type {}", meta.isAutoIncrement(0));
```

The query runs fine in the query tool (PgAdmin 4). It returns a single column, single row result. However, in java, the resultset refuses to give me anything. in the above code, the last line `meta.isAutoIncrement(0)`, similar to `resultSet.getInt(0)` gives the same error that does not make sense to me:

```
 The column index is out of range: 0, number of columns: 1.
```

It's like the column array is secretly empty even though the resultSet is not aware of this.

Comment: You aren't executing a query (SELECT), you are executing an update (INSERT/UPDATE). Consider using `resultSet = preparedStatement.execute();` as shown [in this question's answer with the most upvotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23691715/get-returning-value-from-postgresql-via-java), which will be in autocommit-mode if you don't explicitly switch that off.

Comment: What is the value of the variable `i`?

Comment: ResultSet column numbers start at 1, so getInt(0) is invalid.