# Spring Data JDBC @Modifying with PostgreSQL RETURNING to return data from modified rows

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-data-jdbc

PostgreSQL provides a neat way to return data from DML statements, see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/dml-returning.html

What I tried to achieve is something like the following snipped

```
@Modifying
@Query("DELETE FROM Book b WHERE b.title = :title RETURNING *")
Book deleteReturning(@Param("title") String title);
```

to retrieve the deleted row.
However, this leads to the following exception

```
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [DELETE FROM Book b WHERE b.title = ? RETURNING *]; A result was returned when none was expected.; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: A result was returned when none was expected.
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.java:104)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:72)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.translateException(JdbcTemplate.java:1443)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:633)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:862)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:883)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.update(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.java:321)
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.query.AbstractJdbcQuery.lambda$createModifyingQueryExecutor$0(AbstractJdbcQuery.java:103)
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.query.StringBasedJdbcQuery.execute(StringBasedJdbcQuery.java:85)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor$QueryMethodInvoker.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:195)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:152)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:130)
    ...
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: A result was returned when none was expected.
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.checkNoResultUpdate(PgStatement.java:269)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PgPreparedStatement.java:131)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.lambda$update$0(JdbcTemplate.java:867)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:617)
    ... 95 more
```

Spring Data JDBC states that a modifying query can return void, int and boolean only, see
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jdbc/docs/current/reference/html/#jdbc.query-methods.at-query.modifying

Adding a custom RowMapper leads to the same exception.

```
    public class BookRowMapper<T> implements RowMapper<Book> {
        @Override
        public Book mapRow(final ResultSet rs, final int rowNum) throws SQLException {
            return new Book(rs.getString(1), ...);
        }
    }

    @Modifying
    @Query(value = "delete from Book b where b.title = :title returning *", rowMapperClass = BookRowMapper.class)
    Book deleteReturning(@Param("title") String title);
```

Is there an option to achieve this?

Edit: I am aware of plain JDBC https://stackoverflow.com/a/40787385/1239904 but I would like to go with the Spring way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you annotate the method with `@Modifying` it is executed it is executed as a DML statement which does not return any value except the number of rows updated.

If your statement returns a `ResultSet` you should not use `@Modifying`, so Spring Data JDBC tries to extract the `ResultSet` and create return values for the method from it.

Comment: Thank you. Works as you described it. However, are there really no negative side-effects of omiting @Modifying?

Comment: `@Modifying` changes the method called on the JDBC driver and the way results get processed. That's all.