# UPDATE with RETURNING: Not able to retrieve ResultSet

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jdbc

I’ve tested the following UPDATE-RETURNING statement in my PostgreSQL client, and it correctly updates and returns the updated rows.

However, in Java, I’m not able to retrieve the ResultSet. `statement.execute()` and `statement.getMoreResults()` always return `false` and `statement.getResultSet()` returns `null`, always.

Am I missing something here?

```java
PreparedStatement statement = this.prepareStatement(
    "WITH temp AS (" +
    "    SELECT id" +
    "    FROM mytable " +
    "    LIMIT 5 "
    ") " +
    "UPDATE mytable " +
    "SET updated = NOW() " +
    "FROM temp " +
    "WHERE temp.id = mytable.id " +
    "RETURNING mytable.data"
);

boolean hasResult = statement.execute();

if (!hasResult) {
    hasResult = statement.getMoreResults();
    // hasResult is still false
    // statement.getResultSet() still returns null
} else {
    // statement.getUpdateCount() returns the correct count of updated rows
}
```

Comment: What happens if you use `executeQuery`?

Comment: `executeQuery()` throws an exception when using with an UPDATE rather than SELECT.

Comment: what is the exception? Are you sure the sql is a valid statement?

Comment: The exception when using `executeQuery()` instead of `execute()` is: *org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: No results returned by the query.* And yes, the query works if I copy/paste it and do a SQL request in the SQL console. The rows also get updated accordingly when using `execute()`. But the result is not accessible.

Comment: Looking at [Get RETURNING value from Postgresql via Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23691715/get-returning-value-from-postgresql-via-java), trying `getResultSet` without checking the return value might work (though that would indicate a bug in the implementation, as that wouldn't be JDBC compliant).

Comment: Yeah, I’ve seen that post as well and tried accessing `getResultSet()` directly. It’s `null`. I’m wondering if it has anything to do with the query itself.  Maybe the combination WITH … UPDATE …  RETURNING triggers some weird behavior in Java. I’ll confirm this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I wasn’t really able to solve this properly. However, I ended up using a workaround by wrapping the whole SQL request with a `SELECT` statement:

```java
PreparedStatement statement = this.prepareStatement(
    "WITH results AS (" +
        "WITH temp AS (" +
        "    SELECT id" +
        "    FROM mytable " +
        "    LIMIT 5 "
        ") " +
        "UPDATE mytable " +
        "SET updated = NOW() " +
        "FROM temp " +
        "WHERE temp.id = mytable.id " +
        "RETURNING mytable.data" +
    ") " +
    "SELECT * FROM results"
);

ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();

while (result.next()) {
    // Work with result
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The return code from `execute()` indicates if there is a result available immediately or not.

`getMoreResults()` tells you if there is *another* result set **after** processing the first one that was indicated through the return value of `execute()`.

So the following will work with your UPDATE statement:

```
boolean hasResult = statement.execute();
if (hasResult) {
  ResultSet rs = statement.getResultSet();
  ... process the result ...
}
```

Note that you get a ResultSet even if the UPDATE didn't actually change any rows (e.g. because the WHERE clause didn't match anything). The result set will return false immediately when you call `next()`.

---

You only need to check `getMoreResults()` if you expect more than one ResultSet. Then you would need a loop:

```
boolean hasResult = statement.execute();
while (hasResult) {
  ResultSet rs = statement.getResultSet();
  .... process the result ...

  // check if there is another one
  hasResult = statement.getMoreResults();
}
```

In theory you also need to check `getUpdateCount()` in the loop as well. that would be needed if the database returns a mixture of result sets and update counts. Not sure if Postgres actually supports that though.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. `statement.execute()` always returns `false` in my case above. That’s why `statement.getResultSet()` returns `null`, while `statement.getUpdateCount()` returns a valid number. Probably JDBC can either return an update count or the ResultSet, but not both?

Comment: Are you maybe using an outdated JDBC driver? The code definitely works as described. I'm using it myself in several projects

Comment: That’s interesting. Are you also using it with the combination of WITH … UPDATE … RETURNING?

Comment: Yes, I tried my code with your SQL statement